# Is there any limit to call nlapiSearchGlobal(keywords) method in Netsuite API?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I need to call the `nlapiSearchGlobal(keywords)` API method many times. In the Netsuite API documentation it describes the method as follows:

> **nlapiSearchGlobal(keywords)**
>
> Performs a global search against a single keyword or multiple
>   keywords. This API is supported in client, user event, scheduled,
>   portlet, and Suitelet scripts. **Usage metering allowed for
>   nlapiSearchGlobal is 10 units**.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each running instance of a script, Netsuite enforces a limit on the script's usage of API functions. For example, a User Event Script is allowed 1000 total units of usage, so if you call `nlapiSearchGlobal()` more than 100 times your script will throw a "Usage Exceeded Error", and your script would need to restart to reset the allowance.

You can read more about this topic in the Netsuite documentation in the section "[SuiteScript Governance](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=chapter_N3350651.html)".